# replace method raises error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, pandas

I have an object where I'd like to replace certain values with other values.

```
replacements = {
['object','timedelta[ns]']: 'varchar',
'float64': 'float',
'int64': 'int',
'datetime64': 'timestamp'
}
```

I get an error raised when I try to run the command above `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

I'd like `replacements` to feed into `dataframe.dtypes.replace(replacements)`

EDIT:
Added () to make it hashable: `('object','timedelta[ns]'): 'varchar',`

but now receive this error:

`TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'tuple'`

This isn't a problem if I remove `('object','timedelta[ns]'): 'varchar',` any ideas?

Comment: Because `['object','timedelta[ns]']` cannot be a key in a dictionary, it's a list (unhashable). This isn't to do with `replace`.

Comment: once it's hashable, I get another error saying that I can't compare types. But this error goes away if I comment out the tuple. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say that you should have single key: value pairs: `{'object': 'varchar', 'timedelta[ns]': 'varchar', ...}` but I can't be sure

Comment: Use `timedelta64[ns]`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Breaking them up into single key value pairs gives me this error (TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'). It's only with the timedelta[ns] string. Looks like there might be something wrong with the [] in the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the key a tuple to make it hashable:

```
replacements = {
('object','timedelta64[ns]'): 'varchar',
'float64': 'float',
'int64': 'int',
'datetime64': 'timestamp'
}
```

Furthermore, you need to use `timedelta64[ns]`, not just `timedelta[ns]` because you can only use strings that actually represent existing datatypes. The type `timedelta64[ns]` is from NumPy and is name exactly like that.

Comment: that worked...not sure why timedelta[ns] wouldn't work but timedelta64[ns] would work?

Comment: It does not recognize it as data type and takes it as string.